# How to get the request data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter.

I am trying to print the requested data of form .

I want the bunch of data , but i am unable to fetch it.

Here i am getting single data .I want the whole array of data.

I have tried this below codes .

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Ticket extends CI_Controller {

    public function insert_ticket()
    {   


    echo $title = $this->input->post("title");//getting single data
        print_r($this->input->post);exit;//This one is not working.
    }
}
```

Thank you.Any suggestion?

Comment: You can use print_r($variable) in any framework of php either it is CI, Laravel, Cake

Comment: 'I am new to codeigniter.' 0 so read docs, please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$this->input->post` this is wrong rather you may try as following because `post()` is a method not properties

```
print_r($this->input->post());return;
```

Answer (score 2):

You did a mistake in your code you missing function parentheses `post()` 
code should be like this

```
print_r($this->input->post());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this will may help you

```
 print_r($this->input->post());
 die();
```